# Some intuition about separating hyperplanes and dot products?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, intuition

Lets say we have two sets, $X,Y$, that are separated (in the strict sense) by some hyperplane. (I'll talk about in 3-dimensions as that's how I am trying to picture it, but you can talk about more if you'd like)

I believe then, that there is some vector, $A$, orthogonal to the separating hyperplane, such that the dot product of $A$ with any $x\in X$ is less than the dot product of $A$ with any $y\in Y$ (I believe this is true but am not sure; **If this is not true**, then instead consider two hyperplanes that satisfy the criteria for the [hyperplane separation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane_separation_theorem), and thus there is such a vector, and let me know this isn't true please)

Then, when it is stated that $\langle A,x\rangle < \langle A,y\rangle $ for all $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$, is this saying that:

> If I consider the amount that $A$ moves in the direction of $x$, multiplied by the length of $x$, this is less than the amount that $A$ moves in the direction of $y$, multiplied by the length of $y$, $\forall x\in X\; y\in Y$?

(more formally: The magnitude of $A$ projected onto $x$ (times the magnitude of $x$) is less than
the magnitude of $A$ projected onto $y$ (times the magnitude of $y$) $\forall x\in X\; y\in Y$?)

> Also, when I consider these lengths, do I take the origin to be on the hyperplane? I ask because often when I see hyperplanes depicted I see $A$, the vector orthogonal to the plane, drawn starting at the hyperplane. I realize this may be for easily depicting that it is orthogonal, but I am not sure whether this is the case or if this indicates moving the origin to the hyperplane.

I realize what I take as the origin may not matter for computation purposes, but I asked for purposes of visualization.

Comment: Too complicated.  First, consider a *hyperspace* $H$ (i.e., a hyperplane that passes through the origin).  If $n$ is a vector normal to $H$, then taking scalar products with $n$ can tell us whether two points are on the same side, or on different sides of $H$.  E.g., if $x$ and $y$ are the position vectors of two points, then the products
$x \cdot n$ and $y \cdot n$ have different signs if and only if the two points are on different sides of $H$.  If both products are nonzero (and have different signs), then $H$ separates the two points in the strict sense.

Comment: @avs I know it's complicated but I want to better understand dot products and hyperplanes in an intuitive sense, if possible. That aside, if I have a *hyperplane* (not through origin), it can separate two points and their dot product with $n$, the vector normal to $H$, can both have the same sign (defining vectors as being from the origin). Should I just think about (hypothetically) redefining the origin to be on the hyperplane (perhaps where $n$ would/does intersect it), thus giving the dot products different signs?

Comment: Yes, that's the work with it: translate everything so that the new origin is in $H$.

Comment: Alright, that helps. Thank you.